# Proof explanation in Theorem 4.23, Hatcher's Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory, solution-verification

[image]

During the proof of Theorem 4.23, Hatcher uses Lemma 4.10 to take simplices $\Delta _\alpha ^{m+1}$ and $\Delta ^{n+1}$, but I can't see how did he use the lemma. How did he take the simplices?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can take any simplex (of appropriate dimension) contained in the open set $U$ of Lemma 4.10(b). If you have an affine map $T\colon\mathbb{R}^i\to \mathbb{R}^n$, any half-space in $\mathbb{R}^n$ will pullback to $\varnothing$, $\mathbb{R}^i$, or a half-space in $\mathbb{R}^i$. It follows that for an $n$-simplex $\Delta^n\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, either $T^{-1}(\Delta^n)$ is empty or is an intersection of $\leq n+1$ half-spaces in $\mathbb{R}^i$. Thus if $P\subset \mathbb{R}^i$ is a polyhedron, then so is $(T|_{P})^{-1}(\Delta^n)=P\cap T^{-1}(\Delta^n)$.